# Connect to postgresdb using typescript from nodejs server

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, typescript, middleware

I am new to typescript and nodejs. I wanted to connect a server running on node to postgresdb in a containerized environment. There are examples available for this without typescirpt (only java script ) . 
Any example or link would be helpful .

Thanks

Edit : 
This JS Example

```
const { Client } = require('pg')
const client = new Client()
await client.connect()
const res = await client.query('SELECT $1::text as message', ['Hello world!'])
console.log(res.rows[0].message) // Hello world!
await client.end()
```

This is the example taken from https://node-postgres.com/ and can we convert that into typescript , Using typescirpt is design decision so i cant use javascript, wanted to try something and experiment before giveup on it.

Comment: Although I'd advise to use TypeScript (it's really nice!), most solutions will also work in JS (since TS is compiled to JS in the background), but require a slightly different syntax. Have a look at https://node-postgres.com for some examples that should also work in plain JS. EDIT: You might want to have a look at [container linking](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/postgresql_service/#use-container-linking), but I have no real experience with docker.

Comment: I know how to link containers , thats fine but my inexperience with typescirpt and node and i could not find a better information from online

Comment: I'm confused on whether you want to use TypeScript or JavaScript for the project. Your question states "without typescript (only javascript)", but the edit states that you use TypeScript?

Comment: I wanted to use typescript . But I tried to explain that I could find resources written in JS but not TS, on the edit and wanted to know how can we convert the example script which is JS to TS

Comment: Ah! That explains. TS is really close to JS, so it might look like it's all in JS whilst it isn't really. Can you clarify what your exact problem is? Is it in getting a working connection string, or finding resources on how to use a postgres database in Node with TypeScipt?

Comment: Finding resources on how to use postgres db in node with TS .

Comment: Use types from definitely typed : https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/pg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using typeorm and that can be used with TS. 
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm

Installation and examples available in Github Repo. 
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm#Installation

This might not work for everyone but seems best fit for me and the library looks stable.